# MSAL function missing - FirstOrDefault()

Tags: azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to follow the examples online (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/guidedsetups/active-directory-windesktop) but don't appear to have the correct library installed...?

Via NuGet cmdline: Install-Package Microsoft.Identity.Client -Pre

All the examples on the internet use a method that's part of the PublicClientApplication class, PublicClientApp.Users.FirstOrDefault() to get the same auth token that was received when following the SignOn dialogs.  However this method does not apparently exist in my codebase!?!?!
Does anyone have any insights as to why this might be?  Or insights as to the new workaround for this subject?  I believe the content i'm using hasn't been modified since April 2017..

Microsoft.Identity.Client version = 1.1.2.0, runtime version v4.0.30319

Comment: Follow up...I'm not familiar w/ C#....Library wasn't broken, I am....included a LINQ reference and now we're ok...

Answer (score 0):

Adding a reference to System.Linq resolved the issue originally stated..